# Clonar Header LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um `HEADER` e quero clonar ele em outras paginas *HTML*, estou Tentando pela função `cloneNode();`
porém não estou conseguindo resgatar o valor dele na outra pagina *HTML* usando o `localStorage`

Comment: Não use o processo sugerido na resposta pois abre brechas de segurança a ataques cross-site scripting (XSS), esse processo deve ser automatizado no lado do servidor. Para cada servidor sua linguagem hospedeira oferece ferramentas para realizar essa tarefa.

Comment: Pergunto, existe algum motivo para fazer isso do lado do cliente? **Se o motivo for razoável** posso criar uma resposta mostrando como fazer isso usando Webcomponents.

Answer (score -4):

Não é possível clonar um node mas podes clonar o HTML desse elemento.

```
<header id="my-header">
    Hello
</header>

<script>
    let h = document.getElementById("my-header");
    let h_clone = h.cloneNode(true);

    var data = h_clone.outerHTML;

    localStorage.setItem("header", data);

    var h2 = localStorage.getItem("header");
    document.body.innerHTML += h2;

</script>
```

Comment: Não que seja o processo correto de fazer isso, o que não é. Mas for para fazer essa gambiarra não precisa clonar o elemento se o que interessa é apenas o fragmento de código HTML, https://jsfiddle.net/fnamuche/